# Data URI image embedded in html page to be view in email client

Tags: gmail, embed, knitr, data-uri

I have a html file (generated via knitr package in R). It has a image which is encoded as data uri so there is no need for image attachments. 
Here is the link to that sample.html
http://jsfiddle.net/ebwsozav/

Sending it as an attachment, hasnt been issue but now we want to send this html to be embedded into the content of the email. 
Using mutt, `mutt -e "set content_type=text/html" -- person@gmail.com < sample.html`. 
 
Upon opening the email, I realised that the image couldnt be seen, though the html tables and other content could be. 
Screenshot attached here
[image] 
I read that gmail blocks images. 
Could this the reason and is there a way to circumvent this problem ?

**Update**

Outlook cant view it.

Gmail in Android not able to view.

But surprise,surprise

Gmail in iOS system is able to view the image.

Answer (score 0):

> I read that gmail blocks images.

Partially correct.  Gmail filters data URIs from being displayed in its interfaces, but it allows you to download/forward the original message (including the data URI) to a mail client that doesn't filter it.  It does block (all) images on messages flagged as spam.

> is there a way to circumvent this problem ?

Not exactly.  You have to either use a regular URL or attach the image.  It is intended for there to be no way to use data URIs in their interface.